# What is the best architecture for a business application using WPF & EF?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, architecture, business-application

I'm confused about the architectures which we can use to develop a business application with WPF 4.0 and EF 4.0 technologies.

My first choice was a traditional N-tier architecture contains: UI, Business Logic Layer & Data Access Layer with a disconnected behavior.

In this way I create 3 project for each layer and another project for my Entities/DTOs (Each layer is an assembly). Each layer references only to it's upper and lower layers (That is: UI can see the BLL but can't see the DAL). But all layers have access to the Entity/DTOs assembly for communication purposes.
The problem starts when I want to create a simple CRUD form with a DataGrid for example. The BLL disposes the DataContext of the DAL when returns an Entity/DTO, this is the reason that forced me to use STEs. But yet there are several problems. For example I should call "StartTracking" method for each entity returned from BLL to the UI. In short, I don't sure about this pattern reliability or I think I have to forget about automatic handled CRUD forms.

I use the repository model in my DAL layer but when I search about the repository pattern I find it different. It seems that it's not bad to reference to both of the DAL/Repository and the BLL/Services(Not WCF nor WebServices) layers from the UI and thus we can have a connected environment (Without using STEs).

I see an example in which we can get a person from repository but do something on it using BLL or services:

UI CODE:

```
var person = new PersonRepository().GetPerson(10);
Bll.Salary.PaySalary(person);
```

-or-

```
var person = new PersonRepository().GetPerson(10);
Bll.Person.MarkAsAbsent(person);
```

Or something like that...

With this pattern we can send the Entities/DTOs to the UI in a connected way while the DataContext is alive.

I don't know if I understand the way of using the repository pattern in big projects. I think it's not clear to naming the BLL or services classes and methods in this way. More over the developers might be confused about where to use the repository methods or BLL/service methods or about where to create the methods (in repositories or BLL/service).

I prefer the N-Tier architecture using a good approach to track the Entities/DTOs changes automatically like STEs.

Would you please recommend the best pattern in such situations or/and reference me to some good books or documents about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put together a sample app that may help with some of your questions. You can review the presentation notes and the sample via my blog post here:

http://blog.alner.net/archive/0001/01/01/wpf_ef_4_sig_presentation_2010.aspx

The sample shows using STEs and includes some helpers to make the Entity Framework STEs work better in a desktop client app.

Repositories are there to hide the details of how you get the data. The idea is that you could swap the implementation of a repository from one that uses a local database, to one that uses a remote web service without the upper layers knowing about it.

Comment: Thanks for sample. I'l check it and reply. And about the repository, I thought like you but as I said it seems it can be different!

Comment: Let me know if you have questions on the sample. It's based on a real world WPF app that I've been working on for the past year. As far as the repository stuff goes, there are definitely lots of ideas about how to do it. I think it's important to strike a balance between something that works vs something that's theoretically "pure" but difficult to understand. Getting too abstract makes things very difficult to follow / understand / etc. Find what makes sense to you and go with it. The main goal is "separation of concerns".

Comment: Thanks a lot, It's a great sample! But where is its business logic? We have very large amount of business logic in our project and it's my problem to manage. Although I still ask my question; Can I reference to any layer that I need in the n-tier applications or should I use another pattern? I'm looking for a good n-tier business pattern.

Comment: The question of where to put your business logic is highly dependent on your scenarios. I think there are many plausible answers. You can put it on the middle tier (server) if desired. However, for the most responsive and rich interactions, you'll probably want some / all on the client. In this case you have a couple places that you can put logic:

Comment: - In the model (See Domain Driven Design / DDD). This is good for rules that are always true, regardless of the state of the model. Not good for workflow based rules though.
- In the view model. This is a decent place for rules, but does limit their re-use to the views that use that view model.
- In a "service layer". By service, I don't mean web service, but rather a library.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the article [**Architecture for WPF applications**](http://waf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Architecture%20-%20Get%20The%20Big%20Picture&referringTitle=Home) is any help for you.

You might have a look at the BookLibrary sample application of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)** as well. It shows a WPF MVVM application together with the Entity Framework applying the described architecture.